# If-Else Statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I'm trying to alter the results of a Transact-SQL (MS SQL Server) report that is currently showing:

```
CompanyA     DVCE3
CompanyB     DVCE2
CompanyC     DVCE3
CompanyD     NULL 
CompanyE     DVCE3
```

and I would like it instead to show:

```
CompanyA     36
CompanyB     24
CompanyC     36
CompanyD      
CompanyE     36
```

I'm sure the answer to this is to use some kind of if/else statement or a case statement, but I'm not sure of the syntax of this in T-SQL or where it should go in my query.

My basic query looks like this:

```
SELECT
   companyName
   , term
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id ...
WHERE 
   customerNumber IS NOT NULL
   AND companyName != 'TEST'... ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do the values 36 and 24 come from a specific column (maybe in another table?), or should they be hardcoded into the SQL?

Comment: They should be hardcoded - the 24 and 36 are not being taken from another column, good question.  It's just a more readable result (DVCE3 stands for a 3 year term, or 36 months).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your "term" field with the following:

```
CASE WHEN term='DVCE3' THEN '36' WHEN term='DVCE2' THEN '24' ELSE '' END as term
```

I'll rewrite it for readability:

```
CASE
    WHEN term='DVCE3' THEN '36'
    WHEN term='DVCE2' THEN '24'
    ELSE ''
END as term
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, this works.  The only slight side-effect is that, for some reason, wherever the original was returning NULL, your result is returning the number 0.

Comment: @dvanaria - SQL converts '' to 0 for some bizarre reason when casting as numeric. Put all the numbers in single quotes e.g. `'36'` so it treats that column as a string.

Comment: This gave me the exact output I was looking for (by putting the 24 and 36 in quotes).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you only have a few replacements you could stick them in a `case` statement as below.

```
SELECT
   companyName
   ,CASE term WHEN  'DVCE3' THEN '36' WHEN 'DVCE2' THEN '24' ELSE '' END AS term
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id ...
WHERE 
   customerNumber IS NOT NULL
   AND companyName != 'TEST'... ;
```

If you have more or you will be repeating this logic in other queries you could maybe set up a mapping table (either a permanent table, view, or an inline TVF) that you can then join onto.

Comment: Minor detail: you also need to handle the case for converting NULL to ''.

Answer (score 1):

A Case statement will work.  However a better answer might be to place that data into a table and do a join or just place it into a field in your company table.  This makes it MUCH more extensible in the long run.

```
CREATE TABLE CompanyTerms (
    id INT,
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    Term NVARCHAR(100) NULL
)
```

...

```
SELECT
   companyName
   , c.Term
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id ...
   JOIN CompanyTerm c ON c.id = a.id
WHERE 
   customerNumber IS NOT NULL
   AND companyName != 'TEST'... ;
```

Comment: This sounds like a good suggestion, but for the scope of this report I don't have to worry too much about extensibility, at least not regarding what values could fall in this column in the result.